# Unable to run window functions in Apache Superset with a fresh install and uploaded csv data - near "(": syntax error

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I have uploaded a csv to a new install of apache superset, and I am querying it.  So far it has been fine, but I am trying to use window functions, such as:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY some_timestamp_utc) AS RowNumberRank
FROM StudentScore
```

and

```
select *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY some_timestamp_utc) AS NoId
from StudentScore
```

These are not running (throwing an error saying near "(": syntax error.  What is happening here and how can I use these window functions within superset on my uploaded CSV table?

Answer (score -2):

If you are still having this issue, try putting your column names in doublequotes:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY "some_timestamp_utc") AS "RowNumberRank"
FROM "StudentScore"
```

I've had similar issues with other SQL expressions, and the doublequotes solved my problem.  I can't speak to the window function in particular, but this is worth a shot.

Comment: are you test this answer? please read about how to write good answers in help center. thanks.